# When I use the touchpad to select or scroll, the application menu appears

Tags: touchpad

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my laptop.

Since yesterday, every time I use the touchpad to scroll or select something, the application menu appears.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "application menu"? The same thing you get when you press Alt+Tab?

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes that, and also the "Search on your computer"

Comment: I see. It looks like your touchpad recognizes a 3-finger tap (default action for that is to show the Alt+Tab application switcher) or 4-finger tap (default action is to open the Dash search) instead of what you are doing. The first thing you should do is to clean your touchpad. Maybe some old fingerprint stains are left on it that get recognized as additional fingers. After that you should try again. It's also possible to make e.g. the 3-finger tap emulate a middle-click instead, if you want.

Comment: The same as I thought. I just cleaned my touchpad but problem is still here...Now I'm going to clean it better ahah =)

Comment: What did ou change yesterday that could have caused this new behaviour? Was there an update or something changed in the config? Or some more orangejuice over you touchpad?